# rewardedAdDidDismiss function not getting called

Tags: swift, xcode, admob, swift5

I'm implementing rewarded ads in a chat application and using tab bars with it. I'm having a problem with rewarded that whenever I call the function `rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd()` in  `viewDidLoad` and the ad gets presented when I dismiss the ad the function `rewardedAdDidDismiss` gets called without a problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timerLabelDisplay.layer.opacity = 0.0
    rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd()
}
```

Now as we all now viewDidLoad will be called only one time, and this will not help me if i change the tab bar and get back to it, this mean my ad won't load. So what i did, is i put the `rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd()` in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    removeAdsFreeButton.isEnabled = false
    removeAdsFreeButton.backgroundColor = .gray
    rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd()
}
```

Now when i did this everything seems to be perfect, when i change the tab bar and go back again, my reward ad is loading without a problem. However now, when the ad is dissmissed, the function `rewardedAdDidDismiss()` is not getting called, and i need it to be called and i didn't know why?

here it is the full code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        removeAdsFreeButton.isEnabled = false
        removeAdsFreeButton.backgroundColor = .gray
        rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timerLabelDisplay.layer.opacity = 0.0
    }
    
    func createAndLoadRewardedAd() -> GADRewardedAd?  {
        rewardedAd = GADRewardedAd(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
        
        rewardedAd?.load(GADRequest()) { error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Loading reward ad failed there is a problem here")
            } else {
                
                
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                    self.removeAdsFreeButton.isEnabled = true
                    self.removeAdsFreeButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "ChatiwRed")!.cgColor
                    self.removeAdsFreeButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "ChatiwYello")!.cgColor
                    self.removeAdsFreeButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "ChatiwRed")!.cgColor
                }
                self.removeAdsFreeButton.pulseAnimation()
            }
        }
        return rewardedAd
    }
    
    var didUserGotReward = false
    
    func rewardedAdDidDismiss(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd) {
        self.rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd()
        print("ok now show the timer")
        if didUserGotReward {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
                self.timerLabelDisplay.layer.opacity = 1.0
            }
            timerLabelDisplay.pulseAnimation()
            didUserGotReward = false
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: There is a new Rewarded Ad Api. https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-migration Check it out.

Comment: @NaveedUlHassan5 yeah, i'm using the new api and not the old one

Comment: @user14357836 did you find any solution? I am facing same issue.